# R: GLM: factor level not present in data set, but I still want coefficient

Tags: r, glm, r-factor

When I train a model, and afterwards predict on testing data, sometimes some factor level that is not present in the training data shows up in the testing data, and it gives me an error, because the factor level was not available when training the model.

Working example:

```
mtcars2<-mtcars
mtcars2$gear<-as.factor(mtcars2$gear)
mtcars_train<-mtcars2[1:10,]
mtcars_test<-mtcars2[11:nrow(mtcars2),]
model<-glm(formula = cyl ~ gear,data = mtcars_train,family=poisson(link="log"))
predict(object = model, newdata = mtcars_test)


Error in model.frame.default(Terms, newdata, na.action = na.action, xlev = >object$xlevels) : 
  factor gear has new levels 5
```

I want to get coefficients for all the factor levels for the factor I specifiy in my GLM, and if some level is not in the data, I want this factor to be set to 1 in my GLM object. How can I do this?

Comment: why on earth is this downvoted?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Warning: This is not a good way of dealing with unseen levels and the result will be off. I do not recommend it.**

Having said that, you could do the following. Namely adding the missing level to the levels in the glm model.

```
model$xlevels$gear
[1] "3" "4"
```

as you can see the missing is level 5

```
# adding level 5
model$xlevels$gear[3] <- "5"

exp(predict(object = model, newdata = mtcars_test))
          Merc 280C          Merc 450SE          Merc 450SL         Merc 450SLC  Cadillac Fleetwood Lincoln Continental   Chrysler Imperial 
                  5                   7                   7                   7                   7                   7                   7 
           Fiat 128         Honda Civic      Toyota Corolla       Toyota Corona    Dodge Challenger         AMC Javelin          Camaro Z28 
                  5                   5                   5                   7                   7                   7                   7 
   Pontiac Firebird           Fiat X1-9       Porsche 914-2        Lotus Europa      Ford Pantera L        Ferrari Dino       Maserati Bora 
                  7                   5                   7                   7                   7                   7                   7 
         Volvo 142E 
                  5
```

Comment: will this give me a factor of 1 when predicting?

Comment: this solution gives an error: Warning message:
In predict.lm(object, newdata, se.fit, scale = 1, type = ifelse(type ==  :
  prediction from a rank-deficient fit may be misleading

Comment: That is not an error that is a warning. You get this because there are not enough training records for the glm to work with. I have left out the adjustment to the coefficients. level 5 will be treated as 0, so you will just get the intercept returned. If you want the include this the coefficients need to be adjusted. But that is very dangerous especially with log links etc.

Comment: Ok, thank you much! But I do not understand why this is dangerous at all, and why you do not recommend it?

Comment: 1 you adjust a trained model for unseen factor levels. If these were in the training data your coefficients would be different. Same goes for p-values and all the other estimations. You are going against 200 years of regression modelling by doing this. 2 if you want to handle unseen factors, it is better to remove them from your predictions and not predict anything at all. And if you know there are unseen factor levels make sure you can get a sample of them in your training data or use models that can handle unseen factor levels, mostly by preprocessing train and test.

Comment: Is that why the downvote?
to answer: obviously the predictions would be different if they were in the training data, but for my practical purpose it is necessary to have *some* prediction. I have not alluded to the statistical or practical reasoning behind this, and the example I have given is merely an example, and not the real world use I have of this.

Comment: I didn't downvote, but that is probably the reason for it. And as long as you know what you are doing and why (and document it for colleagues). :-)